# awk misbehaving , where some have long strings (up to 45 characters)?

Tags: awk, gawk, bugs, mawk

I would like to extract the last and first columns of the following file, which I will call `filename`.

```
A   0.400       1.0  1.0      3.0     0.0     1.00  2.0     5.0     1.0   1.00   0.0   0.0  gs100_bs050_rcrs100_rarcinf_core_0400mpc3_df
B   0.400       1.0  1.0      3.0     0.0     0.25  2.0     5.0     1.0   0.25   0.0   1.0  gs100_bs050_rcrs025_rarc100_core_0400mpc3_df
C   0.03021516  4.0  1.0      4.0     0.0     1.75  2.0     5.0     1.0   1.75  -0.5  -0.5  data_c_rh4_rs175_gs10_ra0_b05n_10k
```

I tried `awk '{print $NF, " ", $1}' filename`, expecting to obtain

```
gs100_bs050_rcrs100_rarcinf_core_0400mpc3_df A
gs100_bs050_rcrs025_rarc100_core_0400mpc3_df B
data_c_rh4_rs175_gs10_ra0_b05n_10k C
```

But I obtained instead

```
A0_bs050_rcrs100_rarcinf_core_0400mpc3_df
B0_bs050_rcrs025_rarc100_core_0400mpc3_df
C_c_rh4_rs175_gs10_ra0_b05n_10k
```

on Mac (`gawk v 5.0.0`) and the same with 3 extra spaces at the beginning of each line
on Linux/Ubuntu (`mawk 1.3.3`). I also tried `awk '{printf("%s  %s\n", $NF, $1)}' filename`, but got

```
 A100_bs050_rcrs100_rarcinf_core_0400mpc3_df
 B100_bs050_rcrs025_rarc100_core_0400mpc3_df
 Cta_c_rh4_rs175_gs10_ra0_b05n_10k
```

on Mac. Since the longest string of the last column is 45 characters long. So I then tried:

`awk '{printf("%-50s  %s\n", $NF, $1)}' filename`, but this returned

```
     As050_rcrs100_rarcinf_core_0400mpc3_df
      Bs050_rcrs025_rarc100_core_0400mpc3_df
                Cgs10_ra0_b05n_10k
```

My example fits in the awk limits of 1024 characters per field and 100 fields. Could this be a bug in `awk`?

Comment: Your file is a DOS text file, with carriage-return characters before each newline (i.e. part of the `$NF` value).  Outputting a carriage-return returns the cursor to the start of the line. Convert your data to Unix text with `dos2unix`.

Comment: Interesting comment! I had no idea that the file I was working on would be in DOS format. But I was not the creator. Indeed, `file filename` returns `ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators`, while if I run `file` on the output of `dos2unix` I do obtain `ASCII text`. But when I view `filename` with `emacs` I saw nothing special. So `dos2unix` saved the day. Or simply: `tr '\r' ' ' < filename > newfilename`. Thank you for solving the issue!